# What caused Odin to die?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

(Please don't explain to me what happened in the movie, i.e. the actual scene. I’ve already seen it 100 times.) I'm asking what did he die from? Frigga was murdered; as were the Warriors Three. But for Odin it was not clearly defined.

Was it old age? We do know that Asgardians are born, they live and die just like humans. Was it stress? From the first Thor movie we did see a lot of pressure upon him from his family and then the death of his wife. Or could it have been the imprisonment of Hela? He did say his life was all that was keeping her away. We know he died for sure, but of what?

Comment: You can find some related info here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82023/what-happened-to-odin-in-thor-ragnarok

Comment: Did you not see him turn into glowy things? He clearly lost his mojo...

Comment: Odin may have drawn power from proximity to Asgard, the way Hela did, and been more dependent on it due to his age and injuries.

Comment: This isn't sufficient for an answer but in that scene Odin says that Frigga calls to him.

Answer (score 10):

**Thor blames Loki for Odin's death,** implying that he would not have died had he not been exiled from Asgard.  Of course, Thor might be mistaken about this.

Conversely, **Loki did not seem to have *expected* Odin to die,** though, well, this is Loki so he might be lying about that.

Taking these two points together, and assuming for the sake of argument that they are more or less correct, I believe that being exiled (combined with extreme old age) left Odin without sufficient strength to keep Hela imprisoned, and **the effort simply left him too exhausted to survive,** particularly given that he had no particular wish to live any longer after the death of his wife.

That suggests that he *could* have chosen to release Hela earlier rather than giving up his own life keeping her imprisoned for as long as possible, but she would have immediately killed or imprisoned him anyway, and gone on to attack Asgard without warning.  By holding on as long as he did, and by dying in the way he chose, he was able to ensure that Thor and Loki were at least aware of the attack, that

> he could continue to give Yoda-style advice at critical moments,

and that

> the crown of Surtur was available for the final denouement.

This is speculative, of course, so perhaps someone else can provide a better answer based on Word of God or other canon evidence.  But it does seem to fit the mood of both the scene in question and the movie as a whole.

Comment: Based on what we know I like this answer. The only thing I was thinking to look up was to see if there are more details/information on the time we saw Odin in the Odinsleep during the MCU. I believe it was from the first film when Loki 'pretended' to save Odin and Frigga from the Jotun invaders. Maybe Odin was interrupted in that session and it did not have a chance to "heal" him enough. Or maybe it just didn't matter at that stage and Odinsleep wouldn't help him anyway... he was just too old.

Comment: @Odin1806 I agree with you that the Odinsleep does play a part of it. The fact that he put it off for so long and it was interrupted may as well been a factor. Truth be told he was doing a lot for one being. Hela alone is a handful.

Comment: @Ericallday, if he'd had a full dose, so to speak, would he actually have become young again?  I thought it just staved off death, so to speak - like being a wizard on the Discworld, you don't stay young, you're just old for a lot longer than most people. :-)

Comment: @ Harry Johnston no it would have been just extending his strength stamina and life. Not pushing his years back. In theory it slows his aging process.